# Кто такие смерды?

Tags: этимология

*"- Смерд!

- От смерда слышу!

- Холоп!

- Сейчас милиция разберется, кто из нас холоп!"*

Помните?)) И все-таки, кто такие смерды и кто такие холопы? Меня тут интересует именно лингвистическая сторона их названий. Например, само название "смерд" было дано за то, что они не мылись, или слово "смердеть" появилось позже? И, честно говоря, не совсем понятно, почему оно вообще возникло - на Руси с гигиеной дело обстояло всегда достаточно неплохо, особенно по сравнению с Западной Европой того времени, где мылись два раза в жизни: при рождении и после смерти)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

пока - тезисно, понадобится - напишу подробнее.

Холо́пство — состояние несвободного населения в княжествах Древней Руси, в Русском государстве, отменённая Петром Первым высочайшей резолюцией на докладные пункты генерала Чернышева 19 января 1723 г. По правовому положению холопы приближались к рабам[1]. Не следует путать холопа с челядином. Холоп — раб из местного населения, челяди́н — раб, захваченный в результате похода на соседние племена, общины и государства. То есть челядин — раб-чужеземец, раб-иноплеменник. По сравнению с челядином холоп имел несравненно больше прав и поблажек.[2]
(вики)

Происхождения - от общеславянского хлапъ - раб, более ранняя этимология не ясна.

Смерд - Смерд (мн. смерды) — категория населения по «Русской правде», крестьянин на Руси IX—XIV веков, земледелец. Был изначально свободным (в отличие от холопа), но по мере развития поместной системы постепенно закрепостился.  
(там же)

Слово имеет индоевропейское происхождение - "(простой) человек", "прислуга".

В связи с постепенным уничтожением относительного свободного положения смердов, разница между этими двумя категориями почти исчезла.

Смердеть - от смерда, никак не наоборот. Считалось, что простой человек, тем более несвободный, заведомо пахнет хуже благородного хозяина.   
Естественно, это было недалеко от истины. Чем скотника не мой - сами знаете чем он пахнет.

Comment: Поддержу эту версию и добавлю от себя по поводу запаха: при становлении христианства на Руси во многих областях бани находились под запретом, как атрибуты языческой культуры, ибо до  христианства баня считалась семейным храмом, где очищались не только телом, но и душой. Вот и стали смердеть смерды.